# Chromium Will Not Save Google Credentials

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, chromium, microsoft-edge

I'm looking for a way to get Microsoft Edge (or Chrome) to save the password for a Google account. For years I used Google Chrome and had a very hard time getting it to save my Google account credentials. It finally did at some point. The past two years I've needed to save a second google account and it will not. Always assumed it was a Chrome bug, but for the past 6 months I've been using Edge and cannot get it to save either Google account password. It never prompts to save them. Offer to save passwords is enabled. It offers to save passwords on the other 217 sites I have saved, including plenty using https. The issue has been replicated on six machines. A Dell XPS 9700 laptop, HP Envy 17 laptop, custom built desktop, Old Acer desktop, Old HP desktop, and an HP ProDesk 600 G4 SFF desktop. All machines are running Windows 10 x64 and were attempted on Chrome, all major versions 77 through 90. And all with Edge on all major versions 85 through 90. And yes, that means I tried again on every machine both in Chrome and Edge every time a new version was released.

If anyone has any specific, reproducible steps to get a Windows Chromium browser to save Google credentials, please share them. Or if anyone knows of any random Google URL that authenticates both username and password on the same page, please share that. I think that might prompt the browser to save them and may have been how I got it to work once in the past. Instead, normally Google has you input the username, click next, and then a new pages loads for password input.

Thanks.

Comment: [You can try importing a CSV file that contains your username and password to your account, it’s probably intentionally, not asking you to save the password (at least with Chrome), since your profile session is handled by the browser itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917140/chrome-password-manager-how-to-add-password-manually)

Comment: Thanks, @Ramhound. I enabled the feature in edge://flags/#PasswordImport and that worked perfectly. While that might make sense for Chrome only as you point out, I feel like this could be considered a bug with other non-Google Chromium browsers.

Comment: I don’t believe it to be a bug.  I found numerous threads for Legacy Edge and Firefox about saving Google Account passwords.  It’s something to do with how the field is identified.